# How to set ButtonState Loading in HTML5 CSHTML Page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my HTML entry that fires the GenerateBill() Javascript at the moment :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="loading-example-btn" data-loading-text="Loading..." onclick="GenerateBill()">Generate Bill</a>
```

Here is the GenerateBill() method, this all works fine, all I want to do is add the button state feedback

```
    function GenerateBill() {

        var url = '/PremiseProvider/GenerateBill';
        var data = {
            StartDate: $('#from').val(),
            EndDate: $('#to').val(),
            premiseProviderId: $('#PremiseProviderId').val()
        };

        $("body").load(url, data);

    };
```

Here is a code snippet from the Bootstrap 3 official Site on how to implement the button state feedback:

```
<script>
  $('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading')
    $.ajax(...).always(function () {
      btn.button('reset')
    });
  });
</script>
```

My Question is how can I implement in my GenerateBill script, the bootstrap example uses an Ajax call, can I make it work without making too many changes to what I have?

Comment: Will it not work if you just copy `var btn = $(this); btn.button('loading');` in your `GenerateBill()`

Comment: @irvgk No, that will not work. `$(this)` doesn't have any context inside `GenerateBill()`, and so will not change the button state.

Answer (score 0):

If I might make a few suggestions that will both fix your issue and improve your code.

1. Instead of using an `onclick` event, add an event listener in your javascript, and call the function from there.
2. Add the `.button('loading')` call to that same event listener.
3. Don't leave off the `href` for an `<a>` tag. It will cause some browsers to not show the pointer correctly on hover.

Your link will look as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="loading-example-btn" data-loading-text="Loading...">Generate Bill</a>
```

Leaving your `GenerateBill()` logic alone, the listener you need to add to your javascript:

```
$('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
  $(this).button('loading');
  GenerateBill();
});
```

A working example of this code (with `GenerateBill()` simplified) is available here: http://www.bootply.com/VTSNA1XMcm